# Ruby pattern matching function not working

Tags: ruby, regex

I copied a piece of code from a tutorial where you input a string and a pattern and you get the output with the matching parts of the string marked.

However it only works for literal patterns, for instance, I input "hello" and "l" as a pattern and the output is "hello" with both ls marked.

But if I input "hello" and I say the pattern is "l+" the output is plain hello.

Here's the code:

```
st = "\033[7m"
en = "\033[m"

while true
    print "str> "
    STDOUT.flush
    str = gets
    break if not str
    str.chop!
    print "pat> "
    STDOUT.flush
    re = gets
    break if not re
    re.chop!
    str.gsub! re, "#{st}\\&#{en}"
    print str, "\n"
end
print "\n"
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close.  When you do the `gsub`, you need to enclose the `re` like this: `/#{re}/`

This tells the search pattern to be interpreted as a regular expression, rather than a string literal.  As you have it defined right now, you are searching for the pattern `l+` vs the regular expression "the letter `l` 1 or more times"